# Unknown start to a Protocol Buffer File

Tags: buffer, protocol-buffers, protocols

i'm having trouble figuring out how to create a .proto file for this :

```
0A 01 18 00 00 00 B8 88 0A 02 C2 D3 0B 02 00 00
92 AB 0D 00 92 AB 0D 00 EA C6 0E 02 00 00 0A 01
1C 00 00 00 B8 88 0A 01 C2 D3 0B 02 00 00 80 87
0D 0A 92 AB 0D 00 92 AB 0D 00 EA C6 0E 02 00 00
0A 01 1C 00 00 00 B8 88 0A 01 C2 D3 0B 02 00 00
80 87 0D 65 92 AB 0D 00 92 AB 0D 00 EA C6 0E 02
00 00 0A 01 1C 00 00 00 B8 88 0A 01 C2 D3 0B 02
00 00 80 87 0D 66 92 AB 0D 00 92 AB 0D 00 EA C6
0E 02 00 00
```

so far I have written :

```
message Inner1 {
    uint32 number1 = 20615;
    string string1 = 23864;
    uint32 number2 = 26736;
    string string3 = 29805;
}
```

However it does not work, it seems that each part is chunked by

0A 01 [18 00 00 00]

([18 00 00 00 (dec = 24) int being length])

How would I go about handling this, three "chunks" provided up top. Thanks

Bit more info:

```
{
    "WireType": 2,
    "FieldID": 10,
    "Binary": {
        "Hex": "0A",
        "Full": "00001010",
        "MSB": 0,
        "Dec": 10
    }
},
{
    "WireType": 1,
    "FieldID": 1,
    "Binary": {
        "Hex": "01",
        "Full": "00000001",
        "MSB": 0,
        "Dec": 1
    }
},
{
    "WireType": 2,
    "FieldID": 18,
    "Binary": {
        "Hex": "18",
        "Full": "00010010",
        "MSB": 0,
        "Dec": 24
    }
},
```

As you can see the wiretype is 2, so lendel..

Comment: Not at a PC, but what does it look like at https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode? Does that she'd any light?

Comment: it doesn't run through (no output), I tried others like cyberchef etc, they dont seem to be able to parse it, and protoc --decode_raw, same result (fails)
the only success I get is if I snip out the middle (in between 0a01+length) and then I get a solid result, which makes me believe that its a "wrapper" (discussed above)

Comment: yeah, if those two options fail, then: the data isn't pure protobuf; you'd have to handle the chunk prefixes separately by decoding the header bytes yourself

Comment: Hmm, any suggestion how? currently i'm just splitting them up into chunks with php (language of choice) then running each chunk through protoc, works just fine, other than the output not being good json

Comment: Like mentioned before this is not only protobuf data. https://yura415.github.io/js-protobuf-encode-decode/ states that a t byte 48 it does not understand the format anymore. You need more information on what to expect before you can resolve this.